# Cannot get property 'kotlinOutputDir' on null object - Kotlin and Spock

Tags: android, groovy, kotlin, spock

I am trying to test `Kotlin` classes with `Spock Framework`.
When I had only Java classes in my project, everything was working fine. But after adding kotlin in version `1.1.51` to my project, tests stoped working and now I am receiving such error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugUnitTestGroovyWithGroovyc'.
> Cannot get property 'kotlinOutputDir' on null object
```

I am using Android Studio 3.0 Beta 7

Here is my project and module `build.gradle` files:

### Project `build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta7'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-android-gradle-plugin:1.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### Module `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'groovyx.android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.redione.debtscalc"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.10.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testImplementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.11:grooid'
    testImplementation('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy'
        exclude group: 'junit'
    }    
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: I experienced the same issue after upgrading to AS 3.0 stable. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

## Update

The Groovy Android Gradle Plugin has released v2.0.0, which is compatible with Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0. Edit your root `build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-android-gradle-plugin:2.0.0'
```

The original answer (which should not be used!), I leave for historical purposes.

## Original answer

The short answer is that this should be fixed soon, with the Groovy Android Gradle Plugin v2.0.0, which is currently in progress.

The longer answer (with immediate payoff), is that you can workaround this as follows. See [my comment](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin/issues/156#issuecomment-339830019) on the issue on Github.

The following should be added to `app/build.gradle`:

```
// Ugly workaround for incompatibility between Groovy Android Gradle Plugin 1.2.0 and Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0
// Should be fixed with Groovy Android Gradle Plugin 1.3.0. https://github.com/groovy/groovy-android-gradle-plugin/pull/155
task copyFlavorDebugUnitTestKotlinClasses(type: CopyKotlinClasses)
class CopyKotlinClasses extends DefaultTask {

    def kotlinOutputDir = ["$project.rootDir/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/flavorDebugUnitTest"]

    @TaskAction
    def doNothing() {
    }
}
```

Please note, you must replace "flavor" with your project's actual flavor(s), or remove that if you don't use product flavors.

Comment: Just experienced the same problem after trying out the new version 3 plugin.  I can confirm that this seems to have fixed the problem (hopefully, it won't be long till the plugin fixes this itself).